# Concatenate special characters to the column values based on pattern matching in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table with following column in postgres

```
col1
C29[40
D1305_D1306delinsKK
E602C[20
```

I would like to append a string 'p.' & closing square brackets in row 1 and 3 elements and 'p.' to the row2 element.

The expected output is:

```
col2
p.C29[40]
p.D1305_D1306delinsKK
p.E602C[20]
```

I am running following query, which runs without an error but the expected output is missing.

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE     
                WHEN t.c LIKE 'p.?=[%'
                THEN 'p.'|| t.c || ']'

                ELSE 'p.'|| t.c

         END AS col2

FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use two chained `REGEXP_REPLACE` calls:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('C29[40', '^(.*\[\d+)$', 'p.\1]'), '^(?:p\.)?', 'p.')
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/wq2e5s/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/wq2e5s/2) and the [PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/OTSQ24688).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*\[\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any 0+ chars as many as possible (`.*`), then`[` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

The `^(?:p\.)?` pattern matches an optional `p.` substring at the beginning of the string, and thus either adds `p.` or replaces `p.` with `p.` (thus, keeping it).

Comment: It worked for the 1st and 3rd row. How to add p. in the second row element?